# What exactly is Contempt of Court Acts in 1971, in Indian law?

Tags: freedom-of-speech, indian-penal-code, indian-constitutional-law, contempt-of-court

Recently some people are trying sue people who criticized Indian SC.

> Plea seeks contempt of court proceedings against three for criticising
> SC's comments
>
> Read more [here](https://www.deccanherald.com/national/north-and-central/plea-seeks-contempt-of-court-proceedings-against-three-for-criticising-scs-comments-on-nupur-sharma-1123999.html)

I thought one could easily criticize the Judiciary system as it comes under freedom of speech.

Can we not criticize a court's actions, remarks and judgements? What exactly does a layman need to understand about Contempt of Court Acts in 1971, before criticizing it? What all does Contempt of Court Acts cover?

How does this Indian rule compare with, if any, of USA where recent judgements of Kyle Rittenhouse and over turn of Roe vs Wade were critcized?

Comment: I can't open your link, can you provide a different one please. Or further details and context on what the criticisms were, and by whom etc

Comment: @Rick I have fixed the link.